# Performance of DESC query compared to ASC one in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have two queries in my database. The first one looks to the latest added value with some filters.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM c 
WHERE c.type = "TYPE" 
    AND c.userInfo.email = "someEmail" 
    AND c.userInfo.Id = "someUserID" 
    AND c.metadata.status.type = "someStatus" 
    AND ORDER BY c.metaData.creation_timestamp DESC
```

The second one is the same but it looks for the oldest value.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM c 
WHERE c.type = "TYPE" 
    AND c.userInfo.email = "someEmail" 
    AND c.userInfo.Id = "someUserID" 
    AND c.metadata.status.type = "someStatus" 
    AND ORDER BY c.metaData.creation_timestamp ASC
```

Execution of the first one takes about 50 request units but for the second one it's about 4000. Is there a way to improve performance of the second one without changing the structure of stored objects?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure CosmosDB indexes everything in your JSON documents. If you use just a few attributes in your WHERE and ORDER BY clauses it might be a good idea to tweak that a bit to save on [`throughput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview).

Yes ASC would cost most RUs since it goes through all documents in the collection, in order to improve you can specify the partition key